# Como incluir arquivos em uma View baseado na Rota em Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Eu criei uma view `inicio.blade.php` onde coloquei todo o código que se repete em todas as páginas e criei outras views que estendem essa view.

Criei as rotas para as views definindo um nome para elas desta forma:

```
Route::get('/', 'PainelController@painel')->name('painel');
Route::get('calendario', 'PainelController@calendario')->name('calendario');
```

Porém na view `inicio` existem alguns arquivos que só são usados em algumas páginas.

Eu vi que é possível utilizar condicional pra verificar em qual Rota está, porém do jeito que eu estou fazendo não estão funcionando corretamente. Independente da rota em que estou a condição sempre retorna verdadeiro.

Fiz dessa forma (copiei do modelo que o [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) cria):

```
@if (Route::has('calendario'))
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/owl.carousel.css')}}" type="text/css">
@endif
```

Até mandei imprimir a rota pra ver se estava correto e ela retorna certo, mas a condição sempre retorna verdadeiro:

```
<!--{{Route::currentRouteName()}}-->
```

Caso essa não seja a forma correta poderiam me dizer como se faz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `Route::has` verifica se existe uma rota com esse nome nas configurações de rota, não define exatamente qual é a rota atual que está sendo utilizada, pra isso existe o `currentRouteName()` método que traz o nome da rota utilizada,  adaptando ao seu exemplo:

```
@if (Route::currentRouteName() === 'calendario')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/owl.carousel.css')}}" type="text/css">
@endif
```

<sup>**Referencia:** [**Accessing The Current Route**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#accessing-the-current-route)</sup>

Comment: Aeh! Salvou o dia. Eu bem que comecei a desconfiar disso. Tinha tentado usar o RouteName mas deu erro tmb, creio que foi pela quantidade de sinal de igual que usei que tava errado. Mas desse jeito aí agora funcionou.